# Can't manage to use algorithm packages

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to write some simple pseudocode but I just can't get it to work. It's pseudocode from another paper and I want to change it a little and put it in my paper.

[image]

This is the pseudocode I want to write. I tried `algorithmicx`, `algorithm2e` and `pseudocode` but I can't manage to do it with any of them. Are there easier packages for writing pseudocode? I spent the whole morning trying to write an other piece of pseudocode using `algorithm2e` and it took way too long and the result still looks bad.

And now I get an error that is just ridiculous.

```
    ! Argument of \algocf@If has an extra }.
    <inserted text> 
                    \par 
    l.98            \If
                 {all variables assigned}
```

This is my code (it should be the same as the image):

```
    \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Loop 
            propagate() - propagate unit clauses
            \If {not conflict} 
                \If {all variables assigned} 
                    \return SATISFIABLE
                \Else
                    decide() - pick a new variable and assign it
                \EndIf
            \Else
                analyse() - analyze comflict and add a conflict clause
                \If{top-level conflict found} 
                    \return UNSATISFIABLE
                \Else
                    backtrack() - undo assignments until conflict clause is unit
                \EndIf
            \EndIf
        \EndLoop
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{miniSAT\label{lss}}
    \end{algorithm}
```

sigh, so frustrating, I hate latex so much why isn't there an alternative.

Anyway, if you can help me, thanks a lot, I'm really desperate at this point.

Comment: Please, make this into a minimal example, adding a document class and the packages you load for the algorithms.

Comment: @egreg Having `\label{lss}` within `\caption`, can that affect the compilation?

Comment: @azetina Not at all. The problem is that I don't understand what package provides that syntax for pseudocode. From the error message it seems that `algorithm2e` is involved, but its syntax is completely different (and it doesn't provide `algorithmic`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're using; there's probably a package conflict and also wrong syntax. This produces an output that should be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \LOOP 
    \STATE  propagate() - propagate unit clauses
    \IF {not conflict} 
      \IF {all variables assigned} 
        \RETURN SATISFIABLE
      \ELSE
        \STATE decide() - pick a new variable and assign it
      \ENDIF
    \ELSE
      \STATE analyse() - analyze comflict and add a conflict clause
      \IF{top-level conflict found} 
        \RETURN UNSATISFIABLE
      \ELSE
        \STATE backtrack() - undo assignments until conflict clause is unit
      \ENDIF
    \ENDIF
  \ENDLOOP
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{miniSAT\label{lss}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, i also use algorithm2e in the same document. Is there a way so that i can use both packages? And thx for the help egreg and Werner.

`\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[ruled,noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}`
This doesn't work and removing algorithm gives a bug with algpseudocode.

Comment: @Vincent I don't think that those packages are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet resembles the syntax of `algpseudocode` (from [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)). I've redefined the required `\Return` command, and also defined `\funccall` (short for *func* tion *call*) that sets its argument in *italics*. It also seems like each functional call has an accompanying comment, which I've set using `\Comment`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\algrenewcommand{\Return}{\State \textbf{return}\ }
\algnewcommand{\funccall}[1]{\textit{#1}}% Function call
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Loop 
      \State \funccall{propagate}() \Comment{propagate unit clauses}
      \If {not conflict}
        \If {all variables assigned}
          \Return SATISFIABLE
        \Else
          \State \funccall{decide}() \Comment{pick a new variable and assign it}
        \EndIf
      \Else
        \State \funccall{analyse}() \Comment{analyze comflict and add a conflict clause}
        \If{top-level conflict found}
          \Return UNSATISFIABLE
        \Else
          \State \funccall{backtrack}() \Comment{undo assignments until conflict clause is unit}
        \EndIf
      \EndIf
    \EndLoop
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{miniSAT\label{lss}}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

For each code segment to be on a new line, it has to use some form of `\State` command. `\Loop`, `\If`, `\Else`, ... are all defined in terms of `\State` and therefore don't need to explicitly be called as such. However, your function calls are unknown to `algorithmic` as being a `\State`, so you need to insert this manually.

Adding line numbers is as simple as using `\begin{algorithmic}[1]` instead of just `\begin{algorithmic}`.